# iOS Font looks different in UILabel and UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Hi I am making an arabic supported app. I am using custom fonts for arabic. ArabicTypeSetting. The fonts appear right but only the problem is the text appearing in `UIWebView` looks like broken but in `UILabel` it's appearing fine. In this image the top one is `UILabel` and below is `UIWebView`? I have checked HTML and the fonts are exactly same there but appear broken in `UIWebView` in app. [image]

Comment: It looks like it's duplicated, like there are two "view" with the text.

Answer (score 2):

It's look like the part of the text has bold style. If your font not support bold style, web-kit will render this like on your screen.

Comment: it's not bold style in the html either.
<div style="direction: rtl; text-align: center;"><span style="font-family:arabictypesetting;"><strong><span style="font-size:18px;">اَلْحَمْدُ لِلّٰہِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِين، وَالصَّلاۃُ وَالسَّلام عَلَی النَّبِیِّ الْکَرِيمِ وَعَلیٰ آلِہِ وَاَصْحَابِہِ اَجْمَعِين۔</span></strong></span></div>

Comment: @AsadullahAli Remove the `<strong></strong>` tag?

Comment: Thanks I figured it out it was actually strong tag